# How can I calculate the instantaneous (or close to) taps per second like cookie clicker does in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, time

Right now here is the code I'm using. It only updates when the button is pressed and is the average rather than instantaneous.

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender { 
[self incrementTapCount]; 
NSMutableString *aString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", averageTapsPerSecond]; 
[aString appendFormat:@"%s", " per second"]; 
current.text = aString; 
} 

- (void)incrementTapCount 
{ 
tapCountInPastSecond++; 
} 

- (void)timerActions 
{ 
secondsElapsed = secondsElapsed + .1; 
averageTapsPerSecond = (averageTapsPerSecond*(secondsElapsed-.1) +tapCountInPastSecond) / secondsElapsed ; 
tapCountInPastSecond = 0; 
}
```

On the view did load...

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(timerActions) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
```

I'm trying to get it to update without pressing the button, and not be the average speed, rather the speed at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timer fires every .1 second and you want to keep a "sliding" total of the taps in the last second.  I would suggest an array of 10 integers.  Each time the timer ticks you can add the most recent tap count to the end of the array and subtract the oldest.

```
@property (assign) NSInteger runningTotal;
@property (assign) NSInteger tapsInLastSample;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tapHistory;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.runningTotal=0;
    self.tapHistory=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:11];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(timerActions) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender { 
    self.tapsInLastSample++;
} 

- (void)timerActions { 
    self.runningTotal+=self.tapsInLastSample;
    [self.tapHistory addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.tapsInLastSample]];
    if (self.tapHistory.count >10) {
        self.runningTotal-=[self.tapHistory[0] integerValue];
        [self.tapHistory removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    current.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Taps in last second=%ld",(long)self.runningTotal];
    self.tapsInLastSample=0;
}
```