# iOS timing between taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, timing

I'm trying to keep rhythm between taps. However, I randomly get huge values and I'm not sure why.

```
@implementation GameScene
{
   CFTimeInterval previousFrameTime;
   SKLabelNode* myLabel;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
   previousTimeFrame = 0.0f;
   myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

   myLabel.text = @" ";
   myLabel.fontSize = 12;
   myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:myLabel];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    myLabel.text = [NSSTring stringWithFormat: @"%f", previousFrameTime];
}

//Called every frame
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    //get the time between frames
    previousFrameTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - previousFrameTime;
}
```

Output:
0.65323
0.93527
1.65326
5866.42930 <-- ????
2.52442
5.23156
5888.21345 <-- ?????

What would be causing these random jumps?

Comment: Here is an answer that demonstrates calculating average tap rate - it may give you some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666972/how-can-i-calculate-the-instantaneous-or-close-to-taps-per-second-like-cookie/26667164#26667164

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line seems broken to me:

`previousFrameTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - previousFrameTime;`

Let's look at how this would work if you tapped every second, precisely:

```
1.) previousFrameTime = 1000 - 0; (1000)
2.) previousFrameTime = 1001 - 1000; (1)
3.) previousFrameTime = 1002 - 1; (1001)
4.) previousFrameTime = 1003 - 1001; (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The time delta calculation is correct, but you must then record the last measured time, not the last calculated interval, so...

```
CFTimeInterval currentMediaTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
CFTimeInterval currentInterval  = currentMediaTime - previousFrameTime;

// use currentInterval however you were using previousFrameTime, but now the
// previous time should be recorded as the current time

previousFrameTime = currentMediaTime;
```